# Admin Sharepoint console info

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does anyone knows what is the meaning of red sign?
Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"XXX resources available" refers to overall resource quota available in tenant. The red sign means that you do not have enough resources.

Usually when you create a site collection when resource quota has exceeded limit, you get error message "You have reached the maximum resource usage limit."

It wasn’t that you are nearing your storage usage limit, but that the storage quota was used up.

When we create a new site collection in SPO, the default Server Resource Quote for every site collection is 300. But usually, we will not use so much Resource.

I would suggest you reduce the Resource Usage Quota for the Site Collections(for example, change the number from 300 to 100).

Or you can refer to below article for more information, which has many workarounds provided from Microsoft support.

https://sympmarc.com/2012/03/01/managing-resources-in-sharepoint-online-office365-site-collections-you-are-approaching-the-maximum-storage-limit/